# How to integrate Corona with existing Xcode project

Tags: iphone, xcode, integration, coronasdk

I have an Xcode project (Objective-C). I'm thinking to use the Corona SDK for further development. Is it possible to attach the Corona project to an Xcode project just like it is with cocos2d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Corona is a completely self-contained system and cannot be integrated with external code modules.